# Errors when recording sound in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, audiorecord

I have made an app that records sound and analyses it for frequency. This process is repeated a couple of times every second and thus uses threading.

This does work most of the time, but for some reason in the logcat I get these messages repeated after the first analysis.

Rarely (but sometimes) when I test, the app records no sound. So I'm thinking it has something to do with this error.

```
01-23 13:52:03.414: E/AudioRecord(3647): Could not get audio input for record source 1
01-23 13:52:03.424: E/AudioRecord-JNI(3647): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
01-23 13:52:03.424: E/AudioRecord-Java(3647): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

The code is below, does anyone have any idea where im going wrong? Am I not killing the AudioRecord object correctly? Code has been modifed for ease of reading:

```
public class recorderThread extends AsyncTask<Sprite, Void, Integer> {

short[] audioData;
int bufferSize; 

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Sprite... ball) {

        boolean recorded = false; 
        int sampleRate = 8192;  
        AudioRecord recorder = instatiateRecorder(sampleRate);


        while (!recorded) {  //loop until recording is running

        if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) // check to see if the recorder has initialized yet.
        {
            if (recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
                  recorder.startRecording();  
//check to see if the Recorder has stopped or is not recording, and make it record.                               
            else {             
            //read the PCM audio data into the audioData array

              //get frequency
                //checks if correct frequency, assigns number
               int correctNo = correctNumber(frequency, note);

               checkIfMultipleNotes(correctNo, max_index, frequency, sampleRate, magnitude, note);

               if (audioDataIsNotEmpty())
                   recorded = true;

                   return correctNo;
              }
        }
        else
        {
            recorded = false;
            recorder = instatiateRecorder(sampleRate);
        }
    }

        if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) 
        {
            killRecorder(recorder);
        }

        return 1;
}


private void killRecorder(AudioRecord recorder) {
    recorder.stop(); //stop the recorder before ending the thread
    recorder.release(); //release the recorders resources
    recorder=null; //set the recorder to be garbage collected
}




@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {  
    ballComp.hitCorrectNote = result;    
}

private AudioRecord instatiateRecorder(int sampleRate) {    
        bufferSize= AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*2; 
//get the buffer size to use with this audio record

        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord (AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize); 
//instantiate the AudioRecorder

        audioData = new short [bufferSize];
 //short array that pcm data is put into.        
        return recorder;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you logged your state before `if (recorder.getState() == android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)` so you don't have cases where it is `STATE_INITIALIZED`? Guess that could lead to the device not being properly released.

Comment: https://github.com/vinodselvin/ViCorder/

Answer (score 2):

As your log says that "Could not get audio input for record source 1" that means. Android Device not found any hardware for recording the Sound.

So If you are testing the app from Emulator then make sure that you have successfully attached the mice during recording of the sound or if you are debugging or running it from the device then be sure that the Mic is on to record the Sound.

Hope it will help you.

Or

If above not solve your issue then use the below code to record the Sound as it works perfect for me.

Code:

```
  record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

                if (mStartRecording==true) 
                {
                    //startRecording();
                    haveStartRecord=true;
                    String recordWord = wordValue.getText().toString();
                    String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                    file = file+"/"+recordWord+".3gp";

                    System.out.println("Recording Start");
                    //record.setText("Stop recording");
                    record.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.rec_on));
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile(file);
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

//                      mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
//                      mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);

```
                    try 
                    {
                        mRecorder.prepare();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                    }

                    mRecorder.start();

                }

                else
                {
                    //stopRecording();
                    System.out.println("Recording Stop");
                    record.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.rec_off));
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
                    haveFinishRecord=true;

                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;

        }
    });
```

Hope this answer help you.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Would this apply to recording on the fly? in to a buffer not a file? thanks for your help by the way

Comment: @BenTaliadoros : What do you mean by fly ? I have tested it in real device and also into the emulator. It runs perfect for me. Please leave comment for mwans of recording on the fly.

Comment: @BenTaliadoros : i am waiting for your reply. . .

Comment: i mean the data is passed into a buffer, and then analysis is performed. this is repeated a few dozen times

Comment: @BenTaliadoros : Ok budy. Well My code works for the recording purpose. And All the Best for the otherthings you want.

Answer (score 1):

What stops you having two RecorderThreads running at the same time? Show the code that instantiates one of these objects, executes it, and of course waits for any previous RecorderThread to finish first.

If the answer is that *nothing* stops two RecorderThreads running at the same time, then your use of 'static' will obviously be a problem... a second thread will cause the first AudioRecord to be leaked while open. IMHO it's a good idea to try to avoid using static data.

Comment: I have removed the static variables and updated the code, the same error occurs, any ideas?

Comment: You could try answering my question: "What stops you having two RecorderThreads running at the same time?"

Comment: Well the code works, so nothing, but errore still appear in the logcat, so I was asking what is going on

Comment: Try changing your code so that a RecorderThread *cannot* start until the previous RecorderThread completes. I'd be surprised if that didn't fix things.

Comment: Ok, without giving the purpose of the app away, many quick recordings are taken and analysed, in quick succession. I need the ability to start analysing one even if the analysis is not finished on the one before.

Comment: Right, so you only need to open the AudioRecord *once*, and then every so often you can spawn a thread to perform the analysis. You might want to use setNotificationMarkerPosition() to get notifications for when to spawn an analysis thread. (NB: You may need to duplicate the buffer contents).

Comment: wouldnt leaving AudioRecord running be more computationally expensive then having it on when needed? its a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And I solved it by adding

```
"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>"
```

to the "AndroidManifest.xml"